# Android getDeclaredFields() return a disorder result

Tags: java, android, reflection

I declared a class like this:

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8010508999597447226L;

    public long id;
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String phone;
    public String address;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = Student.class.getFields();
        System.out.println("getFields(): " + fields2String(fields));
        fields = Student.class.getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println("getDeclaredFields(): " + fields2String(fields));
    }

    private static String fields2String(Field[] fields) {
        if (fields != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (Field f : fields) {
                sb.append(f.getName());
                sb.append(",");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The main running result is: (the order is same to my Student.java, my expected order)

```
getFields(): id,name,age,phone,address,
getDeclaredFields(): serialVersionUID,id,name,age,phone,address,
```

But the same code running on Android (4.1.2 Dalvik JVM), the result fields order is:

```
07-28 09:54:14.271 5972-5972/com.ex I/System.out: getFields(): address,age,id,name,phone,
07-28 09:54:14.271 5972-5972/com.ex I/System.out: getDeclaredFields(): serialVersionUID,address,phone,name,age,id,
```

The order is strange, not class order or alphabet order
I noted that the implementation of `getDelclaredFields()` in Android is changed (it's native method `public native Field[] getDeclaredFields();`). It may be impossible to change the behavior. But I still want to known that how to get the ordered fields result.

Comment: The order in which the fields are declared in a class should be irrelevant to the correctness of the code in that or other classes. I'm genuinely curious on what your use case id if you want to/can share it with the community?

Comment: The Javadoc for this method specifies that the return value is not sorted or ordered in any particular way. This has nothing to do with Android, the order on your PC may change if you use a different JVM or updated your current one.

Comment: I updated the problem append the full java source and output.

Comment: Totò, consider the scenario of json or xml serialization and signing of data, where order is important.

Answer (score 1):

If you need them in a particular order you can use [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). In the example below you would get them sorted by name (note that I'm using a lambda as the comparator):

`Arrays.sort(getClass().getDeclaredFields(), (a, b) -> a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()));`

Comment: I edited my problem, I want the .java declared order .

Comment: According to the docs you can't have it. The only way to do so is parsing the source code. I still can't think of any use case for this...

Comment: Alternatively you could do something similar creating an annotation that receives an integer and manually adding different numbers for each field. But I agree with @Totò, I can't think of a good reason to need it. Your problem may be on the application architecture, not on reflection limitations.

Comment: Yes, it's a function of ORM architecture. I want to create pretty create DDL, but it seems to have no better way to do this than add order attribute to filed annotation.